# Program which count chars of selected word

Tags: c, char, counting

Its a homework, sorry for that.
I can't make working program for counting chars in word, for an example:

- I enter the String : My name is peter
- The program asks which word to process..
- I enter the number : 3
- Program says : Count of the Third word is 2.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char text[200],vards[20];
  int i, length,lengthv, count=0,x;
  printf("insert txt\n");
  gets(text);
  length=strlen(text);
  for(i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
    if(text[i]!=' ' && text[i]!='.' && text[i]!=',')
      {
        printf("%c", text[i]);
      if (text[i+1]=='\0') 
              count++;
      }
   else
     {
        if(text[i-1]!=' ' && text[i-1]!='.' && text[i-1]!=',')
          {
            count++;
            printf("\n");
          }          
     }
   }
  printf("detect lenght of wich name\n");
  for(i=0;i<x;i++);
  scanf("%s", &text);
  lengthv=strlen(vards);
  printf("\n The lenght of name is %d", lengthv);
  getch();
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting. Also, describe what the code prints in practice instead of just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: And this code doesn't make nothing you want.

Comment: what is your actual question ? for the input name : peter and if input number is 2, output must be 2 and for input number 3, output must be 1 . You mean the number of times a character occurred in a string?

Comment: by the way you mean count of third word is 2 or count of the third char is 2?

Comment: we cant help you if you just sit and listen our comments instead try to respond them so that your problem gets solved

Comment: yes to count chars of the third word...

Comment: you are confusing you mean letter t ? you mean third letter in the peter word?

Comment: no I type in "My name is peter" and with "3" I mean 3rd word in the sentense. It is word "is", and a count of chars in this word is "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really understand your code, but here is how I would do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char text[200], whichText[200];
  int i=0, length, countWord=0, currWord=1, wordChars=0;

  // Get text input:
  printf("insert txt\n");
  gets(text);
  length=strlen(text);

  // Get word to count:
  while(countWord == 0) {
    printf("Count which word?\n");
    gets(whichText);
    sscanf(whichText, "%i", &countWord);
  }

  // Iterate through each character of the text input:
  for( i=0; i < length; i++ ) {
    // Keep track of which word we are on, by counting spaces:
    if( text[i] == ' ' ) {
      currWord ++;
      continue;
    }
    // While we are on the desired word, count the characters:
    if( currWord == countWord )
      wordChars ++;
  }

  printf("Count of word %i is %i.\n", countWord, wordChars);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for my mistakes, I'm seriously ill, just try to finish my homework...